# sendmail error: Cannot write No such file or directory

Tags: email, email-server, sendmail

I am trying to use `sendmail` out of the box in Ubuntu 16 using the default configuration. (I just need an MTA to deliver mail out from my application.) When I try to send a mail, I get:

> Cannot write ./dfv5T8wZmB004563 (bfcommit, uid=0, gid=115): No such file or directory]

`QueueDirectory` in sendmail.cf says `/var/spool/mqueue`. I created that folder and gave write rights to the world, but the same error message persists. Note that it says doesn't exist and not permission denied. So what folder is it attempting to write to?

Comment: Restart sendmail daemon/daemons and checks log entries generated during startup.

Comment: I purged sendmail*, reinstalled, and it worked fine with default settings.

Comment: Primary suspicion: Your sendmail daemon kept working in deleted directory.  (Recreating directory does not help without restart)

Comment: Could you turn your comment into self-accepted self- answer? It would improve sendmail tag stats :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More background. Mine was a newly installed Ubuntu server on GoDaddy. I didn't install sendmail myself. I discovered I had it only when I installed Postfix and was telneting to localhost on port 25 and the response showed it was sendmail. The files were in /etc/mail.

I uninstalled Postfix and the sendmail was still there. But when I attempted to send any mail, I got that write error.

I killed the sendmail process and then any attempts to restart sendmail resulted in nothing happening, ie no error messages, no sendmail running.

I tried `apt-get purge sendmail` and nothing happened either. I could remove sendmail only with `apt-get purge sendmail*`. I then `apt-get install sendmail` and now it worked.